# wsdl to java classes

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, gradle, wsdl

I have 2 WSDL files and I have to generate java classes from them. I have been told that this thing can be done by this plugin: https://github.com/tklein/gradle-jaxws-plugin . But I don't know how to properly use this. I tried to change the build-test.gradle (wsdlURL= ), but it doesn't work. I don't know how I am supposed to run, use this plugin and where to check if those classes were generated. I hope someone finds the time to help me with this because I really need this problem solved. Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you have a restriction of using gradle to do this?

Comment: I kind of have, but if you can show me another way, I am open to learn that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **wsimport** from java. You can have a idea from this example.

http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-wsimport-tool-example/